# How Does NSZombies Really Work?

Tags: xcode, memory-management, nszombie

I cannot find any detailed apple documentation on how the `NSZombie` really functions.  I understand that its designed to not actually release objects and just maintain a count of references to catch any extra releases, but how would something like this work:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: i];

[array release];

}
```

Since the same variable/object is being allocated/initialized and released in the same application, how would `NSZombie`'s technically handle this?  I know that this shouldn't flag any zombies because every `alloc` has a `release`, but how would Xcode technically handle re-allocating the same memory with different capacities?

Comment: That isn't the same object, or the same memory. You're creating a distinct, new NSMutableArray instance on every pass through that loop. Just because a pointer to each is assigned to `array` does not make them the same object.

Comment: So does the NSZombie allow multiple objects all with separate "array" pointers?

Comment: A pointer merely points to a particular location in memory where the object exists. A given object in memory can have multiple pointers to it, or even none (when it is being leaked). NSZombie acts on the object itself, not pointers to it.

Comment: Ohhhh okay.  That makes sense.  You shoulda put that as an answer so I could accept it.  I was confusing pointers and the objects themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in the comments by [Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson).

Quote:

> That isn't the same object, or the same memory. You're creating a distinct, new NSMutableArray instance on every pass through that loop. Just because a pointer to each is assigned to array does not make them the same object.
>
> A pointer merely points to a particular location in memory where the object exists. A given object in memory can have multiple pointers to it, or even none (when it is being leaked). NSZombie acts on the object itself, not pointers to it.

Answer (score 1):

With Zombies, objects don't actually need to be freed[1] -- the object is simply turned into a "Zombie" at some point after the object's retain count reaches 0. When you message a "Zombified" instance, a special error handler is performed.

1) Freeing Zombies is optional. Unless you really need the memory for a long running or memory intensive task, it is a more effective test to *not* to free the zombies (`NSDeallocateZombies` = `NO`)